# Trying to rewrite a file by copying into a new one after making changes and then renaming to the old filename?

Tags: c, csv, file-io

To run the program we write:
Inventory deduct itemName

Which deducts 1 from the quantity of whichever foodItem we name.

My input is a Comma Separated Value text file (.csv). Here is the text file I saved as (.csv):

```
hotdog, 10, 2, 1.50  
bun, 10, 2, 0.50  
burger, 100, 10, 2.00
```

Scanning into my arrays works. But now I'm a little confused about how I should be rewriting the file. I tried using putc but I'm getting this error for `fputs(item[j],fp2);`

```
74  6   C:\coding\Inventory.c   [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'putc' makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

OK, no more compiling errors. But the replica.csv file that's being created is all weird. I'm trying to get it to be the same format as the .csv above. Any clue where I'm going wrong? Also, `rename` isn't changing "replica.csv" to "inventory.csv". The file is still called "replica.csv"

Thanks.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char command[50], argument[50], str[100];
    int quantity[100], limit[100];
    double cost[100];
    char *item[100];
    char *token, *ptr;

    FILE *fp1 = fopen("inventory.csv", "r");
    if(fp1 == NULL)
    {
        perror ("Error opening file");
    }

    while(fgets(str, 100, fp1) != NULL)
    {
        token = strtok (str,",");
        ptr = strdup(token);
        item[i] = ptr;
        sscanf (token, "%s", item[i]);
        token = strtok (NULL,",");
        sscanf (token, "%d", &quantity[i]);
        token = strtok (NULL,",");
        sscanf (token, "%d", &limit[i]);
        token = strtok (NULL,"\n");
        sscanf (token, "%lf", &cost[i]);
        i++;
    }

    strcpy(command, argv[1]);

            if(strcmp(command,"deduct") == 0)
            {
                strcpy(argument, argv[2]);

                for(j=0;j<i;j++)
                {
                    if(strcmp(argument,item[j]) == 0)
                    quantity[j]--;

                }
                FILE *fp2 = fopen("replica.csv", "w");
                for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                fprintf (fp2, "%s,%d,%d,%.2lf\n", item[j], quantity[j], limit[j], cost[j]) ;
            }
                fclose(fp1);
                fclose(fp2);
                remove("inventory.csv");
                rename("replica.csv", "inventory.csv");
            }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: putc writes a single char, but item[j] holds a pointer to several chars. You probably want something like [fputs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputs) or [fprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: ive changed them all to fputs but im still getting the same error with the same line

Comment: fputs is for strings (ie char*) but not all variables you write are that, some are int, and for them you should use fputc. But I think fprintf would be a better choice in any case.

Comment: proper indentation, please!

Comment: On a side note: you might want to look into how structs work for storing records of data, instead of using multiple arrays. http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex16.html has a nice intro.

Comment: I have it working now thanks for Michael Walz however it doesn't rename the file name to 'inventory.csv' which I hope would essentially  overwrite the original file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `for(j=0;j<i;j++)` loop should be simply this:

```
FILE *fp2 = fopen("replica.csv", "w");

for(j=0;j<i;j++)
{
  fprintf (fp2, "%s,%d,%d,%lf\n", item[j], quantity[j], limit[j], cost[j]) ;
}
```

You are using `fputs` with types other than `char*`, it the program won't compile. And using `putc` with an `int` treats the argument as a char, e.g. with `putc(65, fp)` you will get `A` and not `65` in the `fp` file.

There are probably other problems in your code.

Comment: Makes sense. It works now, except it doesn't rename the file to the old filename (which I'm assuming would essentially rewrite the file)

Comment: The rename doesn't work because the inventory.csv file still exists. You must delete it before. With the `remove("inventory.csv")`. You should check the return value of rename, it returns 0 if the file is successfully deleted; otherwise the `errno` global variable contains the error code. And please accept my answer if it is useful.

Comment: For some reason it's deleting the file after renaming it

Comment: Which file is deleted after renaming which file ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't see either replica.csv or inventory.csv once I've run the program. I'll update the code above quickly to show you what I have

Comment: NVM, i think i had changed to "rw" for both fopen() for the files. any clue why this messed it up?

Comment: Possible. Open the file you want to read with "r" and the one you want to write to with "w".

Comment: yeah thats what i did and it works fine, thanks a lot for all the help

Comment: Consider jpw's suggestion in the comments of your question.